Se dicere vs dicere
I am trying to translate this sentence:
"Habemus tantum se dicere et videre" which would be translated as "We have so many things to say and see".
But the real deal is the following: why do we need to use the reflexive verb here?

Where did you find this? It doesn't look correct.

The verb dicere is not used reflexively. One could possibly contrive an example where se is the object of dicere, but I struggle to come up with a context where that would make sense. You'll often see se as part of an indirect clause introduced by a form of dicere, but that's a different thing.
Your example does not mean what you think it means, nor anything else, because it is not proper Latin. "We have so much to say and see" would be something like Tantum habemus, quod dicamus et videamus (relative clause of purpose). The infinitives are completely out of place here.
